# Error while calling a c# dll from java through a C++ wrapper

Tags: c#, java, c++, wrapper

First, here's my config :
I'm working on a 64 bit win 7 pc, along with a XP 32bits SP3 in a virtual machine.
I use Visual studio 2010 and eclipse.

I'm working with the following components :

- **BusinessDll** : C# dll (32 bits .NET framework 3.5) that I want make accessible to java
- **Wrapper** : C++ dll 32 bits that is meant to forward java calls to C#. It references the c# dll.
- **Wrapper Test** A c++ test exe that call the wrapper functions.
- **Java component** : A test project using jre7 32 bits.

I want to use BusinessDll from Java component so I decided to use jna and a wrapper in C++.

Now here the calling tests I've done:

- Wrapper Test -> Wrapper -> BusinessDll    ----> OK
- Java component -> Wrapper                 ----> OK
- Java component -> Wrapper   -> BusinessDll    ----> **KO**

with the message :

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (0xe0434352), pid=264, tid=6488
#
# JRE version: 7.0_25-b16
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.25-b01 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0xc41f]  RaiseException+0x58
```

Crash stack :

```
Stack: [0x00810000,0x00860000],  sp=0x0085e13c,  free space=312k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0xc41f]  RaiseException+0x58
C  [clr.dll+0xe2b54]  GetCLRFunction+0xd209
C  [clr.dll+0x12849b]  CopyPDBs+0x4ab5
C  [clr.dll+0x2ccacd]  CorLaunchApplication+0x255e5
```

I've got the same result with Win 7 64bits and with the XP 32bits virtual machine.

Follows, the code I used :

**Java component**

```
System.load("D:\\dev\\Wrapper.dll");
public interface BioWrapp extends Library 
{
    Wrapp INSTANCE = (Wrapp) Native.loadLibrary("Wrapper", Wrapp.class);
    void SuperDummy();
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    BioWrapp mysdll = BioWrapp.INSTANCE;
    mysdll.BioSuperDummy();
}
```

**Wrapper**

JavaInterface.h

```
#ifdef BIOWRAPPDLL_EXPORTS
#define BIOWRAPPDLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define BIOWRAPPDLL_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif

namespace BioJavaWrapperNp
{
    class BioJavaWrapper
    {
    public: 
        static BIOWRAPPDLL_API void BioSuperDummy(); 
    };
}
```

DotNetInterface.h

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
    __declspec(dllexport)  void superDummy( );
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Wrapper.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "BioJavaWrapper.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
using namespace BioBusiness;

namespace BioBusinessNp
{
    void BioJavaWrapper::BioSuperDummy()
    {
        BusinessClass::superDummy();
    }
}
```

With BusinessClass part of the BioBusiness  Namespace in the C# dll. And superDummy a method of BioBusiness.

I've been trying for a few days now, any idea is welcome.
Thanks for reading.

Adrien

Answer (score 1):

Your C++ DLL is written by managed C++, I double this this is the reason why you got this exception. I think you can try this:
1. Write the wrapper DLL in native C++, which will call functions in mixed C++ DLL, then mixed C++ will call functions in C# DLL
2. Write the wrapper DLL in native C++, and export the C# DLL as COM, then use this COM component in the native C++ DLL.

One more thing: Internal Error (0xe0434352). 0xe0434352 means this exception generated by CLR. You can get the details of the exception with Windbg. Please read this [article](http://ig2600.blogspot.ca/2009/07/finding-clr-exceptions-with-visual.html)